# Are EXISTING Azure App Service Instances automatically upgraded when a new dotnet core version is released?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

If so how can I check which version runs on a given App Service instance?

If not what is the recommended way to ugrade an App Service instance?

Both questions are about windows versions (but Linux ppl would probably be interested as well)

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are automatically upgraded with new runtimes and SDKs.

You can for example open the Console tab from the left bar after opening the App Service, and enter `dotnet --info` to see the runtime and SDK versions available.

You can also see the state of deployment of new versions at https://aspnetcoreon.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Thanks for the info. indeed `dotnet --info` lists all the dotnet versions.  
Nevertheless one question remains: why does `dotnet --version` always return `2.2.109`?

Comment: Uhh that's weird. Do you have an ASP.NET Core extension installed maybe? Or the version is somehow overridden by something in the folder where the terminal is?